# how to take button hold as an input in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I am trying to create a situation where I can take **"hold 'E' to interact"** type of input. My first thoughts are, start a timer after the button has been held down. After the timer reaches 700 ms, take the action. But the problem, is I don't know how to write that in c# since I am new in this language. Any other approach is also appreciated.

I am adding pseudocode here

```
//pseudocode
//inside the update function

if (e is pressed)
{
   start timer;
   if (timer.time == 700)
   {
      Debug.Log("E is pressed for quite some time");
   }
}
```

Comment: @Chase I think OP is talking about either a button on the mouse or keyboard or a UI.Button .. the question you linked is quite unrelated to Unity...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is use a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

When the user presses down the button, the coroutine would start and if the user stops pressing the button the coroutine would stop.

To do this, your code could look something like:

```
using System.Collections;

[SerializeField] int time;

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) StartCoroutine(Action());
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E)) StopCoroutine(Action());
}

IEnumerator Action ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    // do stuff
}
```

*Thanks to derHugo for spotting an error in my example code - its now been edited.*

Of course there are other ways to go about what you want to do, but I'm thinking a coroutine is your best option because it will then be super easy to add some feedback to the user when they are holding down, in your case, 'E'. For example, you could [fill an image](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html) to create an effect similar to this:

[image: Example Image]

And, well, even if you don't want to do that - coroutines are still a good option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that your `StopCoroutine` will not work this way since you pass in different parameters. I would actually rather use a parameter less routine and get the time threshold from an Inspector field which would avoid that ;)

Comment: @derHugo True, mb. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I did some research on coroutines and this worked for me. Thank you so much